# How to manipulate scss variables in Angular2 components

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, angular2-components

Is there a way I can change scss variables declared in Angular2 component? I want to add the theme dynamically based on user selection and hence need to modify the scss variables. I read about keeping all scss variables in a separate scss file and importing the same in other scss file. But can i import the same in my component file and modify the variables. Is this feasible? TIA

Currently I am using mixin. Code goes here:

```
// Color themes
$themes: (
  default: #ff0000,
  banana: #f1c40f,
  cherry: #c0392b,
  blueberry: #8e44ad,
  leaf: #27ae60,
  nightsky: #2980b9
);


// Helper theme mixin
@mixin theme($name, $color) {
    .#{$name}{
        background-color: lighten($color, 30%);
    }
  .#{$name} {
    h1{
      color: $color;
    }
  }
  .#{$name} {
    nav{
      a{
      color: $color;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But is there a way I can alter the variables inside $themes map from Angular component.

Answer (score 2):

This is **impossible** by nature of Sass: it's a build-time tool, a pre-processor. Angular only knows about CSS (though the `styles` and `styleUrls` property in `Component` metadata).

This means that by the time Angular has got its hands on your styles, Sass has already been compiled to CSS. You **cannot change Sass variables in run-time** because they **do not exist** anymore at that point.

---

You can instead use [custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) and change them via regular JavaScript.