# how to change the global variable inside a scss mixin

Tags: sass, angular-material2, scss-mixins

> theme-variables.scss

```
//---------------------------------------------------------
//Declare a global variable and set it to red color
//---------------------------------------------------------
$fg-primary-text: red; 

//---------------------------------------------------------
//below @mixin is used in styles.scss to pass the custom-theme
//---------------------------------------------------------
@mixin cache-theme-colors($theme) {
   @include set-global-variables($theme);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------
//local mixin to set the global-variable from the $theme using !global flag
//---------------------------------------------------------
@mixin set-global-variables($theme: $theme, $fg-primary-text: $fg-primary-text) {
 $foreground: map-get($theme, foreground); //get foreground from the theme
 $fg-primary-text: mat-color($foreground, text) !global; //get the text color from the theme and set it here using the !global flag

}
```

> component.scss

```
@import "../../../../assets/themes/theme-variables.scss";

.text-color {
    color: $fg-primary-text;  //use the variable (but it is still red)
}
```

**But the color is still red**
My question is: how to set the global variable in scss and change it inside a mixin/function and use it in any component.scss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Atlast I've found a solution, and I'm sharing here for those who need it.
>
> **Note:** I know it's very long.. but read patiently you may get something
> **or correct me If I'm doing anything wrong.**

First start from the theme.service

> **theme.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { OverlayContainer } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ThemeService {

  constructor(private overlayContainer: OverlayContainer) {}

  currentThemeNAME: string = "light-theme";
  //DEFAULT_THEME
  private defaultThemeNAME: string = "light-theme";
  setDefaultTHEME() {
    this.setTHEME(this.defaultThemeNAME);
  }

  //LIGHT_THEME
  private lightThemeNAME: string = "light-theme";
  setLightTHEME() {
    this.setTHEME(this.lightThemeNAME);
  }

  //DARK_THEME
  private darkThemeNAME: string = "dark-theme";
  setDarkTHEME() {
    this.setTHEME(this.darkThemeNAME);
  }

  //TO_SET_THE_THEME
  setTHEME(themeNAME: string) {
    console.log(themeNAME);
    this.currentThemeNAME = themeNAME;
    this.overlayContainer.getContainerElement().classList.add(this.currentThemeNAME);
  }

  //TO_CYCLE_THE_THEME
  cycleTHEME() {
    switch (this.currentThemeNAME) {
      case this.lightThemeNAME:
        this.setDarkTHEME();
        break;
      case this.darkThemeNAME:
        this.setLightTHEME();
        break;
    }
  }

}
```

> **app.module.ts**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';

//CORE-SERVICES
import { ThemeService } from './core/services/theme.service';

@NgModule({
  entryComponents: [...],
  declarations: [...],
  exports: [...],
  imports: [...],


  providers: [ ThemeService ], //<----Important

  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})

export class AppModule {
  //important
  constructor(private themeSRVC: ThemeService) {
    this.themeSRVC.setDefaultTHEME(); //<----Important
  }

}
```

**Lets Assume I've 2 themes**:

> **1) light-theme.scss**

```css
// define 3 theme color
// mat-palette accepts $palette-name, default, lighter and darker variants

$light-theme-primary: mat-palette($mat-grey, 500, 100, 700);
$light-theme-accent: mat-palette($mat-pink);
$light-theme-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);

// create theme (use mat-dark-theme for themes with dark backgrounds)
$light-theme: mat-light-theme( $light-theme-primary, $light-theme-accent, $light-theme-warn);
```

> **2) dark-theme.scss**

```css
// define 3 theme color
// mat-palette accepts $palette-name, default, lighter and darker variants

$dark-theme-primary: mat-palette($mat-grey, 900, 700, 900);
$dark-theme-accent: mat-palette($mat-blue-grey);
$dark-theme-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);

// create theme (use mat-dark-theme for themes with dark backgrounds)
$dark-theme: mat-dark-theme($dark-theme-primary, $dark-theme-accent, $dark-theme-warn);
```

> **styles.scss**

```css
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */

@import './assets/fonts/roboto/stylesheet.css';
@import './assets/icons/material-icons/v42/stylesheet.css';

//important
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

//important: always include only once per project
@include mat-core();

//important: import our custom theme files here
@import './assets/themes/light-theme.scss';
@import './assets/themes/dark-theme.scss';

//important: import the theme cacher
@import './assets/themes/register_components.scss';

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

// to set this theme: 
// set yout component's root element's class
// example-1: <body class="dark-theme"> ... </body>
// example-2: <form [ngClass]="themeSRVC.currentThemeNAME"

.light-theme {
  @include angular-material-theme($light-theme); //set material_theme
  @include set-components-theme($light-theme); //cache_theme
}

// to set this theme: 
// set yout component's root element's class
// example-1: <body class="dark-theme"> ... </body>
// example-2: <form [ngClass]="themeSRVC.currentThemeNAME"

.dark-theme {
  @include angular-material-theme($dark-theme); //set material_theme
  @include set-components-theme($dark-theme); //cache_theme
}

//...similarly register your other themes here
```

> **register_components.scss**

```css
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@import '../src/app/erp/security/erp-login/erp-login.component.scss';
@import '../src/app/erp/dashboard/dashboard.component.scss';
@mixin set-components-theme($theme) {
  //###################################################################################
  //---STEP-(1/3): EXTRACT_PALLETE_AND_COLORS----------
  //https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/core/theming/_palette.scss
  //https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/core/ripple/_ripple.scss
  //###################################################################################
  //---01-PRIMARY---------------------
  $primary-palette: map-get($theme, primary); //<---
  $primary-color: mat-color($primary-palette, default);
  $primary-light: mat-color($primary-palette, lighter);
  $primary-dark: mat-color($primary-palette, darker); //<---
  //---02-ACCENT----------------------
  $accent-palette: map-get($theme, accent); //<---
  $accent-color: mat-color($accent-palette, default);
  $accent-light: mat-color($accent-palette, lighter);
  $accent-dark: mat-color($accent-palette, darker); //<---
  //---03-WARN------------------------
  $warn-palette: map-get($theme, warn); //<---
  $warn-color: mat-color($warn-palette, default);
  $warn-light: mat-color($warn-palette, lighter);
  $warn-dark: mat-color($warn-palette, darker); //<---
  //---04-FOREGROUND------------------
  $foreground-palette: map-get($theme, foreground); //<---
  $fg-base: mat-color($foreground-palette, base); //full_black or full_white
  $fg-primary-text: mat-color($foreground-palette, text);
  $fg-secondary-text: mat-color($foreground-palette, secondary-text);
  $fg-hint-text: mat-color($foreground-palette, hint-text);
  $fg-disabled: mat-color($foreground-palette, disabled);
  $fg-disabled-button: mat-color($foreground-palette, disabled-button);
  $fg-disabled-text: mat-color($foreground-palette, disabled-text);
  $fg-divider: mat-color($foreground-palette, divider);
  $fg-dividers: mat-color($foreground-palette, dividers);
  $fg-elevation: mat-color($foreground-palette, elevation);
  $fg-icon: mat-color($foreground-palette, icon);
  $fg-icons: mat-color($foreground-palette, icons);
  $fg-slider-min: mat-color($foreground-palette, slider-min);
  $fg-slider-off: mat-color($foreground-palette, slider-off);
  $fg-slider-off-active: mat-color($foreground-palette, slider-off-active); //<--
  //---05-BACKGROUND------------------
  $background-palette: map-get($theme, background); //<---
  $bg-color: mat-color($background-palette, background);
  $bg-status-bar: mat-color($background-palette, status-bar);
  $bg-app-bar: mat-color($background-palette, app-bar);
  $bg-hover: mat-color($background-palette, hover);
  $bg-card: mat-color($background-palette, card);
  $bg-dialog: mat-color($background-palette, dialog);
  $bg-disabled-button: mat-color($background-palette, disabled-button);
  $bg-raised-button: mat-color($background-palette, raised-button);
  $bg-focused-button: mat-color($background-palette, focused-button);
  $bg-selected-button: mat-color($background-palette, selected-button);
  $bg-selected-disabled-button: mat-color($background-palette, selected-disabled-button);
  $bg-disabled-button-toggle: mat-color($background-palette, disabled-button-toggle);
  $bg-unselected-chip: mat-color($background-palette, unselected-chip);
  $bg-disabled-list-option: mat-color($background-palette, disabled-list-option); //<---
  //---COMMON_COLORS---------------
  //fetch from the theme directly using the is_dark_mode flag
  $is-dark-theme: map-get($theme, is-dark); //<---
  //primary_text
  $fg-dark-primary-text: rgba(black, 0.87);
  $fg-light-primary-text: white;
  $fg-primary-text-inverse: if($is-dark-theme, $fg-dark-primary-text, $fg-light-primary-text); //<---
  //secondary_text
  $fg-dark-secondary-text: rgba(black, 0.54);
  $fg-light-secondary-text: rgba(white, 0.7);
  $fg-secondary-text-inverse: if($is-dark-theme, $fg-dark-secondary-text, $fg-light-secondary-text); //<---
  //disabled_text
  $fg-dark-disabled-text: rgba(black, 0.38);
  $fg-light-disabled-text: rgba(white, 0.5);
  $fg-disabled-text-inverse: if($is-dark-theme, $fg-dark-disabled-text, $fg-light-disabled-text); //<---
  //dividers
  $bg-dark-dividers: rgba(black, 0.12);
  $bg-light-dividers: rgba(white, 0.12);
  $bg-dividers-inverse: if($is-dark-theme, $bg-dark-dividers, $bg-light-dividers); //<---
  //focused
  $bg-dark-focused: rgba(black, 0.12);
  $bg-light-focused: rgba(white, 0.12);
  $bg-focused-inverse: if($is-dark-theme, $bg-light-focused, $bg-light-focused); //<---
  //---DERIVED_COLORS--------------
  $_bg-ripple: rgba($fg-base, 0.1); //SPEC
  $_bg-list-item: $bg-card;
  $_scrollbar-bg: rgba($fg_icon, .4);
  $_scrollbar-fg: rgba($fg_icon, .05);
  $_scrollbar-hover-bg: rgba($fg_icon, .16);
  $_scrollbar-hover-fg: rgba($fg_icon, .20); //<----
  //###################################################################################
  //---STEP-(2/3): CREATE_GLOBAL_CLASSES_THAT_DEPEND_ON_THE_ABOVE_THEME_COLORS--
  //###################################################################################
  //++++++MAT-LIST-ITEM++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  .mat-list-item {
    background-color: $_bg-list-item;
  }
  .mat-list-item.selected {
    background-color: $primary-light;
  }
  .mat-list-icon {
    color: $fg_icon;
  } //<---
  //###################################################################################
  //---STEP-(3/3): PASS_REQUIRED_COLORS_TO_THE_COMPONENTS-----(note: not the $theme)
  //###################################################################################
  //---Pass_Colors_required_by_the_DashboardComponent
  @include dashboard-component-theme( //---
    $fg-primary-text, $fg-secondary-text, //---
    $fg-primary-text-inverse, $fg-secondary-text-inverse, //---
    $_bg-ripple); //<--

  //---Pass_Colors_required_by_the_erp-Component
  @include erp-component-theme($fg-primary-text, $fg-secondary-text);

 //similarly register all your components here and pass only the required colors
} //--------------------------------------------
```

> **dashboard.component.scss**

```css
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

//colors_passed_by_the register_component.scss

@mixin dashboard-component-theme(    
    $fg-primary-text, $fg-secondary-text, 
    $fg-primary-text-inverse, $fg-secondary-text-inverse, 
    $_bg-ripple) {
 
    //Classes for component's html
    
    .sidenav-header-primary-text {
        color: $fg-primary-text-inverse;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 28px;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
    }
    
    .sidenav-header-secondary-text {
        color: $fg-secondary-text-inverse;
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 2px
    }
    
    .list-item-primary-text {
        color: $fg-primary-text;
    }
    
    .list-item-secondary-text {
        color: $fg-secondary-text;
    }
    
}
```

> **dashboard.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss'],

})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  //###-Important: include the ThemeService
  constructor(private themeSRVC: ThemeService) {
    //...
  }
 
  //...
  
   //---
}
```

> **dashboard.component.html**

```html
<!-- Important set [ngClass] of the root element from the themeSRVC -->

<mat-sidenav-container [ngClass]="themeSRVC.currentThemeNAME">


  <!-- .... -->

  <!-- Include the classes from the component's scss -->

  <h4 class="list-item-primary-text" mat-line>456</h4>
  <p class="list-item-scondary-text" mat-line>123</p>


  <!-- .... -->

</mat-sidenav-container>
```

> That's It..!

Answer (score 1):

You will need a mixin function in your component.scss.

And then have a @include in your main.scss file.

**component.scss**

```
@mixin text-color-mixin($theme) {
  $is-dark-theme: map-get($theme, is-dark);
  .text-color {
    color: if($is-dark-theme, red, blue);
  }
}
```

**main.scss**

```
@import ..<path to file>.../component.scss
...
<Other code>
...
@include  text-color-mixin($theme);
```

To find out more on how you can structure your angular project themes you can look at https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io

This is the official repo for the angular material io documentation site.

**EDIT**

I think this also answers your question

[How to manipulate scss variables in Angular2 components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480320/how-to-manipulate-scss-variables-in-angular2-components?rq=1)

Comment: That's the problem, when I change my theme dynamically I need to pass it to all my components. say If I have 130+ components, then I've to use @include mixin of all the 130+ components. It would've been nicer to store the color values in a global variable when I change the Theme and use it in any component.

Comment: You cannot do that scss compiles to css and there is no such thing as a variable in style sheets. But even if you have 200 variables I don't get why you will have to put the css class in all the 130+ components if you are just deriving the css class from the theme. You can just include that in you main.scss file and just use that css class in all the components. Is there a specific use case that you are doing?

Comment: The actual Requirement is: 1) We need a separate global color variable file, which has all the $color-varaibles. 2) When the app theme changes,  Pass the $theme object to the global color variable file and fill up those $color-variable from the theme,  3) now import the color file in any component, 4) use the color variables to style your html elements.