# How to update the global sass variable from a mixin

Tags: sass, angular-material2, mixins

> **Note: Please Don't Mark it as duplicate, many like myself, are waiting for the answer. we've searched everywhere.**

1) I have a global variable **$global_var_bg** defined as **blue** color in the scss file of a component.

2) I have a **mixin function** in the component's scss file which accepts the $theme argument, which is passed while the global theme changes for the app.

3) **Inside** the mixin function I **change** the global variable **$global_var_bg**.

4) Then access the global variable **$global_var_bg** inside an scss **class**.

5) finally I **assign** the **class** to a **div** element in the component.html, expecting **$global_var_bg** to be the modified **background_color** inside the mixin function.

6) but, its still **$global_var_bg**

> Help me to solve this problem,
>
> Note: I don't want to move the class inside the mixin function.

```css
@import '~@angular/material/theming';


$global_var_bg: blue; //define a global variable


@mixin dashboard-component-theme($theme) {

  $background: map-get($theme, background);

  //modify the global variable inside the mixin function

  $global_var_bg: mat-color($background, background) !global;
}

//access the global variable inside a class
.some-class {
  background-color: $global_var_bg;
}
```

```html
<!-- set the background color of the div -->
<!-- which I expect to be the theme's backround color -->
<!-- but still blue-->

<div class="some-class"> random text </div>
```

Comment: You have to _call_ the mixin before defining the class. Your code only _defines_ the mixin.

Comment: I'm calling the mixin from register_theme.scss, which is called when the user changes the theme... thanks to @Jacob E 's answer now I have got the idea. In a couple of days, I'll post the complete answer.

Comment: An SCSS file or a SASS mixin cannot be called dynamically through application interaction. SASS is source code, not live CSS code. You can achieve your requirement using the provided answer, but the question you've placed in the title has nothing to do with the solution to your requirement provided by Jacob E. It would be helpful for searching/future users if you would completely change the title so that it reflects the application requirement question, not the SASS variable question which is secondary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with theming not based on CSS Variables you could do:

**Example using function map**

```
//  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––-
//  _theme.colors.scss
//  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––- 
//  default theme 
$theme: light !default;

//  theme colors 
$theme-colors: (
    light: (
       text: black,
       back: white
    ),
    dark: (
       text: white,
       back: black
    )
);

// color function returning the color value 
// based on color name and theme
@function color($name, $theme: $theme){
    @return map-get(map-get($theme-colors, $theme), $name);
}


//  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––-
//  _my.component.scss
//  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––-   
@import '_theme.colors.scss';


.class {
    color: color(text);       // black (using the default light theme)
    background: color(back);  // white (using the default light theme) 
}

.class {
    color: color(text, dark);       // white (using the passed dark theme)
    background: color(back, dark);  // black (using the passed dark theme) 
}

//  switching global theme will take effect in all 
//  classes after the point of change 
$theme: dark;

.class {
    color: color(text);       // white (using the now default dark theme)
    background: color(back);  // black (using the now default dark theme) 
}
```

**Example using theme mixin**

```
//  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––-
//  _theme.colors.scss
//  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––- 
//  default theme 
$theme: light !default;

 @mixin theme($theme: $theme){

    @if $theme == light {
        $color-text: silver !global;
        $color-back: white !global;
    }
    @if $theme == dark {
        $color-text: black !global;
        $color-back: white !global;
    }

    //  passed content (classes)
    @content;
}


//  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––-
//  _my.component.scss
//  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––-    
@import '_theme.colors.scss';


@include theme {
    .class {
        color: $color-text;       // black (using the default light theme)
        background: $color-back;  // white (using the default light theme) 
    }
}

@include theme(dark) {
    .class {
        color: $color-text;       // white (using the passed dark theme)
        background: $color-back;  // black (using the passed dark theme) 
    }
}

//  switching global theme will take effect in all 
//  classes after the point of change 
$theme: dark;

@include theme {
    .class {
        color: $color-text;       // white (using the now default dark theme)
        background: $color-back;  // black (using the now default dark theme) 
    }
}
```

**Note!**

Changing theme at a global level could cause unforeseen problems (like when changing import order) – why you can chose not to expose it by defining the default inside the function and mixin

```
@function color($name, $theme: light){ ... }
@mixin theme($theme: $theme: light){ ...}
```

Comment: great answer..., now I have the idea... thank you... soon I'll share my implementation...

Comment: Right now I've achieved it like the last answer I've posted in this post. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53922711/how-to-change-the-global-variable-inside-a-scss-mixin). ur answer is much simpler... I'll implement ur technique and will share it in a couple of days..

Comment: Good to hear :-). Drop a comment if you have questions